# div блок сплющивается при попытке выравнивания снизу по центру

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с меню, я пытаюсь выравнить его по центру в самом низу, но когда применяю position: absolute, блок просто сплющивается и не растягивается нормально до конца контейнера, если убрать absolute блок становится тем каким должен быть но сверху, помогите пожалуйста выравнить блок menu снизу по центру.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Futura";
  src: url("../fonts/Futura.ttf");
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Futura";
  color: #303030;
  background-color: #f5f5fb;
}
.container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 850px;
  max-width: 850px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(52, 46, 173, 0.25), 0 15px 30px 0 rgba(52, 46, 173, 0.1);
}
.main {
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 5%, 12%, 0.733);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.menu {
  margin: 750px 0 0 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff6c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #0f0f1640, 0 15px 30px 0 #0000001a;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item:focus, .menu-item:hover {
  outline: none;
}
.menu-item:focus .material-icons, .menu-item:hover .material-icons {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  color: #313131;
}
.menu-item:focus .menu-item-label, .menu-item:hover .menu-item-label {
  color: #000000;
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: "Material Icons Outlined";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #9e9ea1;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.menu-item-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2a2829a6;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>:3</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined"
      rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            
        </div>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <span class="material-icons">account_circle</span>
                <span class="menu-item-label">Профиль</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <span class="material-icons">shopping_basket</span>
                <span class="menu-item-label">Маркет</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <span class="material-icons">sports_esports</span>
                <span class="menu-item-label">Игры</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="menu-item">
                <span class="material-icons">poll</span>
                <span class="menu-item-label">Топ</span>
            </a>
        </nav>
        <div class=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте для меню стиль `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: @PavelGrishaev блок всё равно приплющенный становится

Comment: Ну так у него считайте что родителя нет, вы же абсолют написали и тем самым вырвали его из потока. Напишите вручную нужную ширину или паддинги понапишите чтобы они расширили. Или можете вместо этого всего написать `left: 0; right: 0;`